# Term for this type of modifier?

Tags: terminology

While programming I've come across some very specific situations where I want a variable/method to have these properties:

- Can be accessed by other classes.
- Can NOT be accessed by sub classes of the class originally containing said variable/method.

Let's forget the practicality of this--I'm just wondering:
Is there, in some language, an *explicit modifier* that does this? If so, what is it called?

Comment: I would be surprised if this had a name, because it makes no sense.

Comment: @jonrsharpe In what way does this make no sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C++ has the **friend** keyword. This can be used in a way that creates exactly what I described.